# JUNIT: Generate exportable reports from Junit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I have a huge Java project with several unit tests in it. What is the best tool available to create exportable reports that provide statistical (e.g. coverage, list of tested functions) information on the unit (JUnit) tests within the project?

Comment: [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) is a quite popular tool for this. You'll need to run sonar in a webserver and have a DB at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) as a maven plugin, but I think you could use it standalone, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to run the test cases and generate the report.

Please see this link: http://kirankanumuri.blogspot.in/2010/09/generating-junit-html-reports-using.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview) for this. But it costs a fair few pennies.